# Mink + Driver couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink, sahi

I am trying to get Mink working on Centos/Apache, but it cannot connect. I have tried with Selenium2Driver, ZombieDriver and last Sahi but I always get a different error.

Right now with **Sahi**:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\SahiDriver('firefox');
$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

$session->start();

$session->visit('http://google.it');

echo $session->getStatusCode();
```

and generate this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Buzz\Exception\RequestException' with
>   message 'couldn't connect to host' in
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php:29
>
> Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Browser.php(130):
>
> Buzz\Client\Curl->send(Object(Buzz\Message\Request),
>   Object(Buzz\Message\Response)) #1
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Browser.php(82):
>
> Buzz\Browser->send(Object(Buzz\Message\Request)) #2
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Browser.php(36):
>
> Buzz\Browser->call('http://localhos...', 'POST', Array, '') #3
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/behat/sahi-client/src/Connection.php(268):
>
> Buzz\Browser->post('http://localhos...', Array, '') #4
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/behat/sahi-client/src/Connection.php(150):
>
> Behat\SahiClient\Connection->post('http://localhos...') #5
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/behat/sahi-client/src/Client.php( in
>   /var/www/html/Test/vendor/kriswallsmith/buzz/lib/Buzz/Client/Curl.php
>   on line 29

I have installed with composer:
behat/behat
behat/mink
behat/mink-sahi-driver
behat/sahi-client

Why it cannot connect?